# Does $G\times H$ have a dual when $G$ and $H$ have?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be two groups with duals. Does $G\times H$ have a dual?

A group $G$ has a dual iff the lattice of its subgroups is order-isomorphic to the dual of the subgroup lattice of some other group (or $G$ itself).